Does EF optimize projections to named types like it does for anonymous types?
In the Microsoft EF tutorial Efficient Querying, the section Project only properties you need describes how to make EF load only specific columns by projecting the entity queryable to an anonymous type. They don't provide a code example, but to extend their other examples, it might look like this:
context.Blogs.Select(b => new { b.Id, b.Url })

My question is, will EF also recognize what you're doing and load only the required columns if you project to a named type like this?
context.Blogs.Select(b => new BlogModel { Id = b.Id, Url = b.Url })

Or like this?
context.Blogs.Select(b => new BlogModel(b.Id) { Url = b.Url })


Yes in all cases. Examine SQL to ensure by yourself.

No difference. When projecting I will use the property accessor method on concrete classes as I find it is simpler where I want to return data, or anonymous types where I just need to pull data just for the scope of the method.
One important piece of advice though when projecting to a concrete instance: Use a dedicated view model/DTO class rather than a new instance of the entity class, especially when partially filling data. The reason is that if you are passing that data around to other methods or sending it to a Form-based view etc. you are bound to start having methods that accept a "Blog" entity that can be re-used and that code will be vulnerable to bugs if it expects to be given an actual Blog entity, vs. a Blog instance that was partially populated by a projection. If you instead have a BlogViewModel or BlogDTO class for the projection, there is no confusion when calling methods that expect a Blog entity vs. a BlogViewModel.  Code that accepts an entity should be able to trust that it is a complete, or completable copy of the data. Ideally a tracked and fully populated instance.

I didn't mean to imply that Blog was the entity type. Edited for clarity.

No worries, it is something I come across on projects that leads to headaches when teams are passing around detached entities, which is bad enough, but then partially filled detached entities... :)
